# How does printf influence getrusage measure time in C

Tags: c, printf, getrusage

I probably missed some important point of getrusage() function.

When I run the following code, I get:

User time:      0.000000 s
System time:    0.000000 s
Total time:     0.000000 s

```
void naiveSearch(unsigned char *text, unsigned int textLen, unsigned char *pattern, unsigned int pattLen) 
{
  register unsigned int count = 0;
  for(int i=0;i<=textLen-pattLen;i++)
  {
    int j;
    for(j=0;j<pattLen;j++)
      if((unsigned char)text[i+j] != (unsigned char)pattern[j])
        break;

    if(j == pattLen)
       count++;
  }
  //printf("naiveSearch: count = %d\n",count);
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
  struct rusage ruse;
  double ssec1, ssec2, usec1, usec2;

  getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF,&ruse);
  ssec1 = (double)(ruse.ru_stime.tv_sec * 1000000 + ruse.ru_stime.tv_usec);
  usec1 = (double)(ruse.ru_utime.tv_sec * 1000000 + ruse.ru_utime.tv_usec);

  for(int k=0;k<1000;k++)
    naiveSearch(writeBuffer,outSize,writeBuffer+rand,16);

  getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF,&ruse);
  ssec2 = (double)(ruse.ru_stime.tv_sec * 1000000 + ruse.ru_stime.tv_usec);
  usec2 = (double)(ruse.ru_utime.tv_sec * 1000000 + ruse.ru_utime.tv_usec);

  printf("User time:\t%f s\n",(usec2 - usec1)/(double)1000000);
  printf("System time:\t%f s\n",(ssec2 - ssec1)/(double)1000000);
  printf("Total time:\t%f s\n",((usec2 + ssec2) - (usec1 + ssec1))/(double)1000000);

  return 0;
}
```

However, when I run the same code with printf() function (inside of naiveSearch) uncommented, I get some expected/realistic time. Why the zero time is measured in the first case? How can I reliably measure the time?

Thank you for any idea. P.

UPDATE: There must be some safe and reliable way how to test algorithms in a loop. I need to include all the standard compiler optimizations and still do all the iteration of the same algorithm. Is there any way how to do that? How to test time performance with certainty that time results represent all the iterations performed?

Comment: almost certainly the compiler has optimized out your code, since it does nothing, try returning count and printing it, now the compiler cant throw the code away.

Comment: What compiler, what flags and plz give actual reproducible code.

Comment: My guess is that most likely your program doesn't use much CPU.  Why don't you try printing out some other stats.

Comment: I use the following gcc flags: CFLAGS = -O3 -mavx -msse2. I guess it must be caused by some compiler optimization. It cannot be because of low CPU usage since I test the search algorithm on 100 MB text file. This force me to update/extend my question (see the end of my original post).

Comment: -O3 tells the compiler to optimise out stuff, do it with -O0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that your program doesn't use enough CPU to get the timer to show anything.  Probably the clock tick isn't sensitive enough for your naiveSearch function to generate anything.  Also, there's no reason to cast the times to doubles.  Try doing something like this:

```
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int runalot()
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = 1;

    for (i = 0; i < 100000000; i++) {
        if (i % j == 4) {
            j += 1;
        }
    }
    return j;
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    int j;
    struct rusage ruse1, ruse2;
    double ssec1, ssec2, usec1, usec2;

    getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF,&ruse1);
    j = runalot();
    printf("runalot returns %d\n", j);
    getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF,&ruse2);
    printf("CPU usage is: %lu\n", ruse2.ru_utime.tv_sec * 1000000 + ruse2.ru_utime.tv_usec - ruse1.ru_utime.tv_sec * 1000000 + ruse1.ru_utime.tv_usec);
}
```

When I compile it with gcc on Linux with the -g debugging flag, and run it, I get `CPU usage is: 372000`.